# iOS11, large titles with nested UINavigationControllers and UITabBarControllers possible?

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, ios11, xcode9

I am upgrading one of my customer's applications to Xcode 9 / iOS11 and I was trying to get large titles to work. They look absolutely fine but I run into [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46346521/xcode-9-ios-11-calayer-bounds-contains-nan-nan-0-nan-0-when-popping-view) [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46252019/) when I am popping a view from the navigation stack.

The root cause seems to be that I nest a `UITabBarController` sometimes to have a row of options below the screen. This is advised against but it used to work like a charm. It still works fine whenever I leave the titles to the old style.

There's a possibility to have large titles in this set up or should I replace the `UITabBarControllers` with something I custom create that has a `UITabBar` at the bottom and mimics most of what the `UITabBarController` does.