# UINavigationController method setToolbarHidden bug in Xcode 9: infinite calculation of auto-layout constraints leads to OOM

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, ios11

I have an instance of `UINavigationController` nested in `UITabBarController`. I use the navigation controller to reach some view controller (tab bar still visible), from which I segue to a second view controller (tab bar no longer visible).

In the second view controller, as soon as I make a call to:
`[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO]`
the app freezes and memory grows until OOM exception crashes it.

I acknowledge that nesting the navigation controller inside the tab bar is not recommended, but this setup seemed to work fine until iOS 11.

**EDIT:** when stopping execution, I see a lot of calls to:

`UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout)`

`UIView(AdditionalLayerSupport)`

`NSLayoutConstraint`

Here's the full stack trace

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP   * frame #0: 0x0000000106dd895c libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend
+ 28
    frame #1: 0x00000001067b6b9b Foundation`-[NSConcreteMapTable removeObjectForKey:] + 138
    frame #2: 0x00000001069e6019 Foundation`_substituteOutAllOccurencesOfBodyVar + 1282
    frame #3: 0x00000001067f3c5b Foundation`-[NSISEngine tryAddingDirectly:] + 144
    frame #4: 0x00000001067f332f Foundation`-[NSISEngine tryToAddConstraintWithMarker:expression:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:]
+ 440
    frame #5: 0x00000001069f2067 Foundation`-[NSLayoutConstraint _addLoweredExpression:toEngine:integralizationAdjustment:lastLoweredConstantWasRounded:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:]
+ 273
    frame #6: 0x00000001067ea601 Foundation`-[NSLayoutConstraint _addToEngine:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 240
    frame #7: 0x0000000109c9488d UIKit`__57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
_switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 452
    frame #8: 0x00000001067f0de1 Foundation`-[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 131
    frame #9: 0x0000000109c946a2 UIKit`__57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
_switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 604
    frame #10: 0x0000000109c9441e UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 223
    frame #11: 0x00000001091ed84f UIKit`__45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 112
    frame #12: 0x00000001067f0de1 Foundation`-[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 131
    frame #13: 0x00000001091ed778 UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 855
    frame #14: 0x00000001091fe031 UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1927
    frame #15: 0x0000000109b507e1 UIKit`-[_UILayoutArrangement insertItem:atIndex:] + 502
    frame #16: 0x0000000109ca1b4d UIKit`__50-[_UIOrderedLayoutArrangement insertItem:atIndex:]_block_invoke + 50
    frame #17: 0x0000000109ca18df UIKit`-[_UIOrderedLayoutArrangement _trackChangesAffectingExternalBaselineConstraints:] + 320
    frame #18: 0x0000000109ca1aea UIKit`-[_UIOrderedLayoutArrangement insertItem:atIndex:] + 478
    frame #19: 0x000000010982edea UIKit`-[UIStackView insertArrangedSubview:atIndex:] + 283
    frame #20: 0x0000000109b29972 UIKit`-[_UIButtonBar _layoutBar] + 3639
    frame #21: 0x0000000109b2bb44 UIKit`-[_UIButtonBarStackView updateConstraints] + 48
    frame #22: 0x0000000109c958b6 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
_sendUpdateConstraintsIfNecessaryForSecondPass:] + 161
    frame #23: 0x0000000109c95ed2 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
_updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 1296
    frame #24: 0x0000000109c95d51 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
_updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 911
    frame #25: 0x0000000109c95d51 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
_updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 911
    frame #26: 0x0000000109c95d51 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
_updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 911
    frame #27: 0x00000001067f0de1 Foundation`-[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 131
    frame #28: 0x0000000109c96703 UIKit`__100-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
_updateConstraintsIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:]_block_invoke
+ 90
    frame #29: 0x0000000109c94f61 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
_withUnsatisfiableConstraintsLoggingSuspendedIfEngineDelegateExists:] + 104
    frame #30: 0x0000000109c96272 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
_updateConstraintsIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:] + 160
    frame #31: 0x0000000109c9738c UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
_updateConstraintsAtEngineLevelIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:]
+ 401
    frame #32: 0x00000001091ef1b6 UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 1517
    frame #33: 0x000000010957b35e UIKit`-[_UIButtonBarButton willMoveToWindow:] + 63
    frame #34: 0x00000001091ec996 UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) _willMoveToWindow:] + 861
    frame #35: 0x00000001091eb493 UIKit`__UIViewWillBeRemovedFromSuperview + 484
    frame #36: 0x00000001091eb0ea UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 95
    frame #37: 0x0000000109b295d3 UIKit`-[_UIButtonBar _layoutBar] + 2712
    frame #38: 0x0000000109b2bb44 UIKit`-[_UIButtonBarStackView updateConstraints] + 48
    frame #39: 0x0000000109c958b6 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
_sendUpdateConstraintsIfNecessaryForSecondPass:] + 161
    frame #40: 0x0000000109c95ed2 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
_updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 1296
    frame #41: 0x0000000109c95d51 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
_updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 911
    frame #42: 0x0000000109c95d51 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
_updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 911
    frame #43: 0x0000000109c95d51 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
_updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 911
    frame #44: 0x00000001067f0de1 Foundation`-[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 131
    frame #45: 0x0000000109c96703 UIKit`__100-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
_updateConstraintsIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:]_block_invoke
+ 90
    frame #46: 0x0000000109c94f61 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
_withUnsatisfiableConstraintsLoggingSuspendedIfEngineDelegateExists:] + 104
    frame #47: 0x0000000109c96272 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
_updateConstraintsIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:] + 160
    frame #48: 0x0000000109c9738c UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
_updateConstraintsAtEngineLevelIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:]
+ 401
    frame #49: 0x00000001091efa5b UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) _updateConstraintsAsNecessaryAndApplyLayoutFromEngine] + 159
    frame #50: 0x00000001095742d5 UIKit`-[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 270
    frame #51: 0x0000000109204551 UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1331
    frame #52: 0x00000001064db4ba QuartzCore`-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 153
    frame #53: 0x00000001064df5a9 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 401
    frame #54: 0x00000001064681cd QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 365
    frame #55: 0x0000000106493ae4 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 500
    frame #56: 0x0000000109160687 UIKit`_afterCACommitHandler + 272
    frame #57: 0x00000001080f8db7 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
+ 23
    frame #58: 0x00000001080f8d0e CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 430
    frame #59: 0x00000001080dd324 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1572
    frame #60: 0x00000001080dca89 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    frame #61: 0x000000010dc429c6 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 62
    frame #62: 0x0000000109135d30 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 159
    frame #63: 0x0000000101ff6bf9 MyAppName`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff5de3e0a8) at main.m:23
    frame #64: 0x000000010f453d81 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #65: 0x000000010f453d81 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the answer from a developer from the same team as OP is from.

After one more round of research we have found that the problem was on our side:

```
- (NSArray *)toolbarItems
{
  return [self toolbarItemsWithRunningAdditionalAnimation:NO];
}
```

Original developer made the method `toolbarItemsWithRunningAdditionalAnimation` to return new objects each time the method was called. When going to this controller iOS calls `toolbarItems` at least 3 times so giving it new objects every time we made iOS confused so it was recalculating auto-layout constraints in an infinite loop. Our original fix below is also working, however it becomes obsolete as we start always returning the same array of items like:

```
- (NSArray *)toolbarItems {
  if (_cachedToolbarItems) { return _cachedToolbarItems; }

  _cachedToolbarItems = [self toolbarItemsWithRunningAdditionalAnimation:NO];

  return _cachedToolbarItems'
}
```

---

We are doing the following in our app (pseudocode):

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = self.navigationController.toolbar;

NSArray <UIBarButtonItem *> *items = @[
  flexibleSpace, 
  share, 
  flexibleSpace, 
  play, 
  flexibleSpace, 
  stats, 
  flexibleSpace
];
[toolbar setItems:items animated:animated];

[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:animated];
```

The problematic items that caused infinite calculation of auto-layout constraints were `share` and `stats`. The thing they both had in common - they both were created using `-[UIBarButtonItem initWithImage:style:target:action:]` initializer. When we started using another initializer:

```
 UIButton *customShareButton = ... // we create button ourselves.
 UIBarButtonItem *shareItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: customShareButton];
```

The problem went away.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the accepted answer, we found that our problem was related to the fact that in our class, we override the method
`- (NSArray *)toolbarItems`.

Every time our method is called, a new set of toolbarItems is created.
Seems like from iOS 11, every time **new** toolbar items are returned to this method, `UINavigationController:layoutIfNeeded` is called again, which in turn calls `toolbarItems` which returns new items because of our implementation. This causes an infinite loop.

If you encounter this problem, check if you are overriding `- (NSArray *)toolbarItems`